# What is the name of the % change calculation where from -1 to 1 is considered +200%?

Tags: percentages

I'm doing some work in a domain where it is normal to say that if the value was `-1` and is now `2` There has been a `+300%` change.

To give some other examples:

```
  ( 10,  5) ->  -  50%
  ( 10, -5) ->  - 150%
  (-10,  5) ->  + 150%
  (-10, -5) ->  +  50%
```

Ie. if the value was `10` and it's now `5`, there has been a `50%` decrease. If the value was `10` and it's now `-5`, the change has been a `150%` decrease. Etc.

The equation is:
$$\frac{\text{value_latest} - \text{value_previous}}{abs(\text{previous_value})}$$

Does this calculation have a name? I am trying to research some of it's properties but I'm not sure what to google.

Comment: It is a strange idea to consider the percentage change if negative numbers are allowed. Maybe someone can mention a situation where this idea has actually a merit since I cannot imagine such a situation.

Comment: It's common in finance. Eg "Profits are up 600% from a \$10 loss last year to a \$50 gain this year". I fully grasp that this is not what percentages are meant to be - but think of it as a domain specific definition.

Comment: @ryang - your link to "Relative Change" is exactly what I was looking for - if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps ‘change relative to the absolute value’, or ‘relative error’ (as opposed to ‘relative change’) ?

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference (sections 2 & 4).